# Is it possible to run the "AsyncTask" method inside another method "AsyncTask"?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have an activity that when started makes a call to a "json" for get data categories of songs, after that I make a call to the method "AsyncTask" for the list of songs that category from another "JSON "the problem is that when I start the activity, this is locked , after 2 seconds, the activity opens the layout and I can see the categories on the action bar and not because the songs are looking for in the background.

main activity (onCreate):

```
    java.io.InputStream source = null;
    source = retrieveStream(UrlApi.URL_BASE + UrlApi.URL_STORE + _bundle.getString("_id") + UrlApi.CATEGORY_SONG);
    Log.i("URL - KARAOKE", UrlApi.URL_BASE + UrlApi.URL_STORE + _bundle.getString("_id") + UrlApi.CATEGORY_SONG);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
    Type happyCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<String>>() {}.getType();
    _karaoke_category_response =  new Gson().fromJson(reader, happyCollection);
    if(_karaoke_category_response.size() < 1){
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Local sin karaokes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Log.i("Category - response", _karaoke_category_response.toString());
        _karaoke_category_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.spinner_item,_karaoke_category_response);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(_karaoke_category_adapter,  this);
    }
```

The follow code is of search the songs of that categori and set it

```
    class AsyncKaraoke extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String category;

    public AsyncKaraoke(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        java.io.InputStream source = null;

        try {
            source = retrieveStream(UrlApi.URL_BASE + UrlApi.URL_STORE + _bundle.getString("_id") + UrlApi.KARAOKE_URL + UrlApi.FILTER_CATEGORY + URLEncoder.encode(category, "UTF-8"));
            Log.i("URL - KARAOKE", UrlApi.URL_BASE + UrlApi.URL_STORE + _bundle.getString("_id") + UrlApi.KARAOKE_URL + UrlApi.FILTER_CATEGORY + URLEncoder.encode(category, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        Type karaokeCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<KaraokeModel>>() {}.getType();
        _response = new Gson().fromJson(reader, karaokeCollection);
        Log.i("Response - KaraokeCategory" , _karaoke_category_response.toString());
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Void){
        super.onPostExecute(Void);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        _karaoke_adapter = new KaraokeAdapter(KaraokeActivity.this,  _bundle.getString("_id"), _response);
        if(_response.size() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Categoria sin karaoke", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        _list_view.setAdapter(_karaoke_adapter);
        _karaoke_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

How should I do to call 2 times to "AsyncTask" method and prevent the activity is engaged by a few seconds?

Comment: u can call the asynctask again on onPostExecute() method... in that u can set flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary rule of `AsyncTask` is that it must always be create and run on the main thread.  You will get an exception if you start another `AsyncTask` inside the `doInBackground()` method.  Your options are to start the next `AsyncTask` in one of the callbacks.  Generally, some people will chain `AsyncTask` in the `onPostExecute()` method, but you can also start them in `onPreExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

EDIT:

Additionally, you can run AsyncTask in sequence of each other using [AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29). From HoneyComb on, you don't need to do this. All AsyncTask run in a serial thread pool in the order they are executed. Though it may be easier to understand that the code is running serially if you use it.  You do need to chain if using Android Android 1.6 - 2.3.x though.

Comment: I think you can actually run more asynctasks at once if you are sure the device has a processor with enough cores.

Comment: @Ayoub what option I hace for old smarthphones?

Comment: Chainig like said by the others

Comment: @Ayoub You can run as many AsyncTask as you want. All it does is wrap the Java Thread mechanism for easy-to-use UI updating. In all versions of Android, except 3.0, AsyncTask will run serially. Though, it's recommended you use `executeOnExecutor()` with `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` to ensure that.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, AsyncTask in versions 1.6 to 2.3.x run in parallel.  From 3.0 (HONEYCOMB), they run in a serial thread pool one at a time unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should build the URL in the main activity, then run an AsyncTask to download the content and finally process the result back in your activity.

The syntax to run an AsyncTask is:

```
String category = "...";
new AsyncKaraoke().execute(category);
```

You can also remove the onPostExecute() method from your AsyncKaraoke class and put it in the activity:

```
String category = "...";
new AsyncKaraoke() {
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void Void){
    // do stuff (and moving the third type of the AsyncKaraoke to something else
    // than Void will allow you to get the result here.
}.execute(category);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we use `AsyncTask` to perform an action in another `thread` than the `UI` thread to prevent the user from being halt while performing some actions. **SO,** it does not make any sense to create an additional `AsyncTask` inside the outer one. Try to manage your code to do it all the those method `soInBackground()`, `onPreExecution()` and `onPostExecution()` and make use of their order of execution

Comment: It does make sense if you want to split functionality among multiple asynctask.  A ListView may need an initial AsyncTask to load some data, then each list item may need their own image loaded or something.

Comment: I agree with you. Splitting the tasks into multiple AsyncTask is ok, but not a nasted AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;

protected void onPostExecute(Void Void){
        super.onPostExecute(Void);

        // call same asynctask
          if (count == 0)
            {     
                execute asynctask
                count++;
            }
}
```